# Can Dragon Shards augment implements?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, implements

I'm used to dragon shards being used on weapons and I'm feeling that they should, but nothing in the dragon shard item descriptions says one way or another and their does not seem to be an appropriate glossary entry in the compendium.

I ask because a friend is looking at making a fire elementalist and hoping to use the Shard of the Fiery depth.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No, dragonshards cannot augment implements.**

I can see why you might think so; from PG Eberron, pg111 (*emphasis mine*):

> ... When bound to an existing magic *item*, a properly attuned dragonshard can also augment or improve the *item's* capabilities.

Unfortunately, every single dragonshard published explicitly has the `Dragonshard Augment (Weapon)` keyword, and is thus only useable on a weapon.

**There's a workaround, though.**

Some objects can be used as both a weapon *and* an implement. Because they're weapons, they can receive dragonshard augments. Because dragonshard augments just say, "You gain a +X bonus to damage rolls with Y attacks against Z", rather than "You gain a +X bonus to damage rolls with Y *weapon* attacks against Z", once a weaplement (the slang term for an object that is both a weapon & an implement) is augmented the dragonshard's bonus applies to **all** attacks made with the object, regardless of whether it's being used as a weapon or an implement.

If your friend has proficiency with staff implements, they can use a quarterstaff. Daggers work, too. They can also take Arcane Implement Proficiency to gain the implement proficiency with light blades or heavy blades.

Answer (score 1):

If your implement is an augmentable weapon the dragonshard can be used.

This applies if you either have a weapon that can be used as a specific kind of implement, or are using a weapon that can be enchanted as either an implement or a weapon. So Staffs and Daggers are in, orbs, wands etc are out.